# Rate of corona discharge

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, dielectric

In a corona discharge, the air around a conductor locally breaks down but remains an insulator further away from the conductor. Therefore, in the case of a positively charged conductor, the free electrons in the locally ionized patch of air can enter the conductor, positively charging the air too. However, corona currents don't exceed a few micro-amps. What is the reason for this? I know that electrically charging the increases the effective size of the conductor lowering the peak electric field. However, can this current be increased to arbitrarily high values is the charged air sheathing the conductor is removed quickly through some other mechanism?

**In essence, what I am asking is if the current limitation of corona discharge is due to the sheathing effect of the charged air or something intrinsic to the conductor-air system such as the probability of a free electron jumping into the valance band of the conductor being low.**

Where can I read about the microscopic nature of corona discharge? Any good books would be appreciated. I would like to learn more about the statistical mechanics behind the free electron and valance band interaction of metals.